# Disable recording notifications in Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center

I have a television with a recording schedule. I have moved and no longer have cable or any television signal. I'd rather not clear the recording schedule, as I might have television again in a few days, but this means that if I want to use Windows Media Center for any other purpose, I have to acknowledge a dozen failed recording notifications first. These pop up on schedule in the middle of other watching. Is there any way to turn these notifications off?